# Sum values from onclick get request foreach jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum up values I get from json get request in jQuery. Instead it keeps replacing the values instead of summing up in variable `total`.

Please how do i sum up the values from each click?

Heres my code

```
$(".checks").on("click", function(){
  var clicked = $(this);
  var room = clicked.val();
  var total = 0;

  if(this.checked) {
    $.get('/rooms.json', function(data){ 
      data.forEach(function(d){
        if(room == d.id){
          total += parseInt(d.room_type.price);
          $("#selected_rooms").append("<p>" + d.number + " @ " + d.room_type.price + "</p>");
          $("#total_amount").html("<p>" + total + "</p>");
        }
      });
    });
  } else {
    $("#selected_rooms").
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to initialize the `total` variable outside of the `click` event handler.

```
var total = 0;
$(".checks").on("click", function(){
  var clicked = $(this);
  var room = clicked.val();

  $.get('/rooms.json', function(data){ 
    data.forEach(function(d){
      if(room == d.id){
        total += parseInt(d.room_type.price);
        $("#selected_rooms").append("<p>" + d.number + " @ " + d.room_type.price + "</p>");
        $("#total_amount").html("<p>" + total + "</p>");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks this works!.. Please how do I remove the specific appended value when click is unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared the variable `total` inside the event handler function, a new variable `total` with value `0` is being declared in each click.

Declare the variable `total` outside of the click event handler function which will retain the previous value:

```
var total = 0;
$(".checks").on("click", function(){
 .........
```

To remove the html if the checkbox is unchecked, you can use `.html('')`:

```
else {
  $("#selected_rooms").html('')
}
```

From the update what I have understood is, you want to clear the the element in each click. For that you do not need the `else` part at all. Simply clear the element in each click just before condition:

**Full Code:**

```
var total = 0;
$(".checks").on("click", function(){
  var clicked = $(this);
  var room = clicked.val();
  $("#selected_rooms").html('');

  if(this.checked) {
    $.get('/rooms.json', function(data){ 
      data.forEach(function(d){
        if(room == d.id){
          total += parseInt(d.room_type.price);
          $("#selected_rooms").append("<p>" + d.number + " @ " + d.room_type.price + "</p>");
          $("#total_amount").html("<p>" + total + "</p>");
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks this works!.. Please how do I remove the specific appended value when click is unchecked?

Comment: @PriinceAbalogu, what do you mean by *when click is unchecked*

Comment: I have updated my question.. basically the click is on a checkbox, so the click runs the function on "check".. now i want to remove appended on "unchecking" the checkbox

Comment: in else loop total -= parseInt(d.room_type.price);